# How do I troubleshoot high vmstat sy

Tags: unix, solaris, cpu-usage, vmstat

I have a Solaris server with very high vmstat sy time.  What tools can I use to identify which process is causing the high system cpu usage?

```
kthr      memory            page            disk          faults      cpu
 r b w   swap  free  re  mf pi po fr de sr m1 m1 m1 m2   in   sy   cs us sy id
 0 0 0 21776984 15540976 355 1968 43 15 8 0 0 1 1 1  1 4206 14471 7300 7  2 91
```

Comment: 2% isn't what I would call a "high vmstat sy"

Answer (score 1):

ps -aefl and look at the 'C' column, the higher the C value the more CPU it is using at
the time you did the ps.

top is also a pretty traditional method.